# Getting and saving user click in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi I am an intermediate codeigniter user and I have an application whereby I want to save the number of clicks in a database. If a user clicks a button(Read More) I want it to get saved in the row of the particular post and if a user clicks on another link I want it to get saved int the row the clicked post in the database. Thanks

**Database**(id, post, post_image, created_at, clicks).

**VIEW**:

```
 <div class="card-image">
      <img src="<?php echo site_url() ?>assets/images/posts/<?php echo $post['post_image']; ?>">

      <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red" href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'. $post['slug']); ?>"><i class="material-icons">Read More</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <span class=" center card-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></span>
        <small class=" center post-date"> Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?> in <strong><?php echo $post['name']; ?></strong></small><br>
<!--THIS IS THE DOT DOT DOT THAT TRUNCATES THE  POST LENGTH-->
<p>  <?php echo word_limiter($post['body'], 40) ; ?></p><br><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post the code that you are using to do that and tell us where you are stuck, so that we can help you with your particular issue.

Comment: We need your code to help you, but you can do this with hooks or saving the info in every controller in the constructor

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to send an AJAX request (get or post really) on every click, or you can sniff out in your controller what the request was and save it to the DB before you render the page out.

If you need a refresher on [jQuery and AJAX requests](https://she-builds-websites.com/presentations/single/jquery-ajax-requests) I actually recently made a presentation about that and walk through the process.

You could try appending the CI url with a get query string to track what button the user clicked, if it's not immediately obvious to your next controller.

Comment: I know it would be implemented with jQuery and AJAX I just dont know how to implement it and I have edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want save in your database, Ajax.

Also you maybe use google analytics with "ga events" or [piwik](https://github.com/piwik/piwik).